# Отделяется ли запятой "то есть"?

Tags: пунктуация

Ну, например, "То есть(,) они вообще не могут писать грамотно". Я запятую поставил, а мне сказали, что она тут не нужна.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая действительно не нужна. "То есть" не является вводным словом, это пояснительный союз.